# Apply a statistical rule every two columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (DF) that looks like this:

```
  PC1.gene       PC1.pc   PC2.gene   PC2.pc     PC3.gene  PC3.pc    
  TGFBI       0.05105828  CEACAM8 -0.08092082  METTL7B -0.09437686      
 HLA-DPB1     0.04843209     LCN2 -0.07883489  ZDHHC19 -0.08424212     
   PI3       -0.04819604    OLFM4 -0.07768484   CYP1B1 -0.08057477      
   IRF8       0.04807908    DEFA4 -0.07471874    CD177 -0.07385733    
   CA4       -0.04705324  CEACAM6 -0.07279997  PLEKHG1 -0.07007224     
   LY86       0.04480976     CTSG -0.07190130   CD300E -0.06989912
```

I would like to get the outlier genes for each PC1.pc column so that the following statistical criteria will be applied every two columns of a data.frame of 180 columns and 8000 rows:

statistics:

```
qrt <- quantile(DF[,2], c(0.25, 0.75))             
iqr <- qrt[2]-qrt[1]             
out1 <- sum(DF[,2] < qrt[1] - 1.5*iqr)
out2 <- sum(DF[,2] > qrt[2] + 1.5*iqr)
OUT = out1 + out2
```

In other words I would like to apply these few lines every two columns and get the gene names with corresponding values.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "for each PC1.pc column" ? There is only one column with that name in the example data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset `DF` for every second column with `DF[,1:3*2]` and then use `apply` to run your script over every column.

```
DF <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="PC1.gene       PC1.pc   PC2.gene   PC2.pc     PC3.gene  PC3.pc    
  TGFBI       0.05105828  CEACAM8 -0.08092082  METTL7B -0.09437686      
 HLA-DPB1     0.04843209     LCN2 -0.07883489  ZDHHC19 -0.08424212     
   PI3       -0.04819604    OLFM4 -0.07768484   CYP1B1 -0.08057477      
   IRF8       0.04807908    DEFA4 -0.07471874    CD177 -0.07385733    
   CA4       -0.04705324  CEACAM6 -0.07279997  PLEKHG1 -0.07007224     
   LY86       0.04480976     CTSG -0.07190130   CD300E -0.06989912")

apply(DF[,1:3*2], 2, function(x) {
qrt <- quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75))             
iqr <- qrt[2]-qrt[1]             
out1 <- sum(x < qrt[1] - 1.5*iqr)
out2 <- sum(x > qrt[2] + 1.5*iqr)
out1 + out2  
})
#PC1.pc PC2.pc PC3.pc 
#     0      0      0
```

but I think you want something like this to *get the gene names with corresponding values*.

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  qrt <- quantile(DF[,i*2], c(0.25, 0.75))             
  iqr <- qrt[2]-qrt[1]
  out <- (DF[,i*2] < qrt[1] - 1.5*iqr) | (DF[,i*2] > qrt[2] + 1.5*iqr)
  DF[out,c(i*2-1,i*2)]
})
```

Comment: or subset with `DF[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`.

Comment: @Roland Yes, this was already in another answer which has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Verbose tidyverse approach, but will identify any gene names more than 1.5x the IQR above or below the IQR.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%              # Track original row number
  gather(PC, value, -rowid) %>%      # original column name,  value
  separate(PC, c("PC", "type")) %>%  # split PC into two columns
  spread(type, value) %>%            # spread based on 2nd part (gene / pc)
  mutate(pc = as.numeric(pc)) %>%    # convert pc back to number
  group_by(PC) %>%           
  mutate(q25 = quantile(pc, 0.25),
         q75 = quantile(pc, 0.75),
         iqr = q75 - q25) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(pc < q25 - 1.5*iqr |        # only keep outlier rows
        pc > q75 + 1.5*iqr)
```